# Is check_admin_referer really needed in plugins activation/deactivation?

Tags: php, wordpress, security, nonce

In my plugins' code, upon activation/deactivation/uninstall I use to perform a check_admin_referer() like this.

```
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'activate_plugins' ) )
        wp_die(__("Insufficient privilege for the required operation"));
    $plugin = isset( $_REQUEST['plugin'] ) ? $_REQUEST['plugin'] : '';
    check_admin_referer( "deactivate-plugin_{$plugin}" );
```

Actually, googling around about Wordpress' security good programming habits, this seems to be a well known practice.
However, I'm having troubles using the TGM-Plugin-Activation framework.

This framework, is used to handle situations in which a certain plugin or theme needs, as a dependency, other plugins. This framework lets me handle the case by setting up a page where the final user can install/update the required dependencies.
However, this page has it's own (fancy?) nonce verification mechanism which is crashing completely my check_admin_referer() verification.

According to the TGMPA developer, a check_admin_referer() upon activation/deactivation is redundant since it's performed internally by Wordpress itself.

In short, my question is: is check_admin_referer() really a safety measure? Is it really needed? Or can it be safely ignored, as the TGMPA developer is suggesting?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: It's one way of (basic) CSRF protection; but if that is handled by another means already (token), then I don't think it is necessary or even adds much benefit. (On the contrary, it could make things break for legitimate admin requests, if the referrer is manipulated by some kind of personal firewall.)

Comment: Thanks, @CBroe. But how can I be sure that this kind of protections is in place (already)? Even the TGMPA developer, who is telling me that Wordpress is performing a check_admin_referer() upon activation/deactivation, is _using it's own code_ for that purpose. In short, I cannot be really sure that this check is in place.

Comment: Have you checked their plugin authoring guidelines for that?

Comment: @CBroe Sure. They're quite vague about that. That's why I'm wondering if, in general, it's a good idea to perform a check_admin_referer() (as it seems to be suggested googling around) or not.